# Perforce - Windows server 2016 can't connect from client

Tags: windows, azure, perforce

I am trying to set up my `Azure` `Virtual machine` to become a `Perforce` remote repository server.

First let me take you through the installation of `Helix` on the server:

[image: ![enter image description here]

And after the install is complete it says:

[image]

So far so good now from my client computer (my local desktop) I attempt to connect to this server, however, I get an error:

[image]
Now first I thought that the port wasn't open in my inbound so I added the following network rule in my Azure cloud portal:

[image]

However, this didn't do anything for me and I get the same error.

So now I am left kinda stranded. Has anyone had this issue and know how i can connect to my remote machine from perforce?

From the comment below when i type p4 info i get the following:

```
User name: ******
Client name: PerforceServer
Client host: PerforceServer
Client unknown.
Current directory: c:\Users\*****
Peer address: 127.0.0.1:50413
Client address: 127.0.0.1
Server address: PerforceServer:1666
Server root: C:\Users\*****\VersionControl
Server date: 2018/11/21 14:44:12 +0000 Coordinated Universal Time
Server uptime: 00:01:27
Server version: P4D/NTX64/2018.2/1724420 (2018/11/02)
Server license: none
Case Handling: insensitive
```

However using the prefix PerforceServer:1666 i still cannot connect

When running netstat:

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50688        PerforceServer:1666    TIME_WAIT
  TCP    127.0.0.1:50689        PerforceServer:1666    TIME_WAIT
```

Also if i run `p4d` i get the following error:

```
Perforce server error:
    Listen 1666 failed.
    TCP listen on 1666 failed.
    bind: 0.0.0.0:1666: WSAEADDRINUSE
```

Comment: This is a Perforce issue, not Azure...
https://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.051/manuals/p4guide/02_connect.html

Comment: @Rthomas529 ive updated my question if you know a solution to my problem i would be very grateful

Comment: Is perforce service is actually running. When you install servers like this you usually need to start the service and configure it to start on server reboots. Also make sure the server can be pinged or telnet to it.

Comment: @Rthomas529 since i can do p4 info and it tells me information about the server i am guessing it is started i can also see it in my services window

Comment: run a netstat -i on the server. What ports are listening?

Comment: @Rthomas529 ive updated the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184042/discussion-between-marc-rasmussen-and-rthomas529).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allow the port through the Windows firewall.

1)Press Windows logo + X keys on the keyboard and select Control panel from the context menu.

2)Select System and Security from the options and click on Windows Firewall from right side panel of the window.

3)Click on Advanced settings and select Inbound Rules from left side panel of the window.

4)Click on New Rule under Actions tab from right side panel and select Port radio button from the window.

5)Follow the onscreen instructions and check if the changes are effective.